# gunicorn: No Module named 'wsgi'

Tags: python, docker, flask, gunicorn

I have a project that is set up to run with docker One one machine which is ubuntu I have been running it fine but recently I have tried to run it on my windows laptop and am getting a ModuleNotFoundError.

```
[2018-01-05 20:31:46 +0000] [5] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.7.1
explore_1   | [2018-01-05 20:31:46 +0000] [5] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8080 (5)
explore_1   | [2018-01-05 20:31:46 +0000] [5] [INFO] Using worker: sync
explore_1   | [2018-01-05 20:31:46 +0000] [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8
explore_1   | [2018-01-05 20:31:46 +0000] [8] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
explore_1   | Traceback (most recent call last):
explore_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 578, in spawn_worker
explore_1   |     worker.init_process()
explore_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 126, in init_process
explore_1   |     self.load_wsgi()
explore_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 135, in load_wsgi
explore_1   |     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
explore_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
explore_1   |     self.callable = self.load()
explore_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
explore_1   |     return self.load_wsgiapp()
explore_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
explore_1   |     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
explore_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 352, in import_app
explore_1   |     __import__(module)
explore_1   | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wsgi'
explore_1   | [2018-01-05 20:31:46 +0000] [8] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 8)
explore_1   | [2018-01-05 20:31:47 +0000] [5] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
explore_1   | [2018-01-05 20:31:47 +0000] [5] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

I checked to make sure my environment variables for paths are set up correctly. Are there any common gunicorn issues that may cause this or other things that stand out as obvious checks?

The dockerfile for this container is as follows:

```
FROM python:3
MAINTAINER dev@temboinc.com
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY requirements.txt /usr/src/app/
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
COPY . /usr/src/app
ENV MODE dev
EXPOSE 8080
VOLUME /static
COPY src/static /static
RUN python3 setup.py install
#CMD python3 wsgi.py
CMD gunicorn -w 3 -b 0.0.0.0:8080 wsgi --reload
```

Comment: Apparently there is no file called `wsgi.py`? what is in /usr/src/app in the docker container?

Comment: after some tooling with the dockerfile it looks like COPY . /usr/src/app is not copying the wsgi.py up even though it is in the same directory as the dockerfile. not sure why this behavior would be different between docker on linux and docker on windows though.

Comment: Check your versions of docker, they may differ between windows and linux.

Comment: I have seen this pattern of keeping the wsgi.py (file/module) in app folder. since you are doing COPY . /usr/src/app  and if I assume wsgi.py file is present in at /usr/src/app/wsgi.py then all you need to do is add WORKDIR /usr/src/app before the last line. making wsgi.py available at base location.

Answer (score 15):

To change to the project folder you can use the command **--chdir**.
Example:

```
gunicorn -w 2 -b 0.0.0.0:8000 --chdir /code/myproject myproject.wsgi
```

Answer (score 5):

You're asking `gunicorn` to run either a file name `wsgi.py` in your current directory, or a module named `wsgi`. The latter could simply be a directory named `wsgi/` which includes an `__init__.py` file (therefore you'd need `wsgi/__init__.py`.

If your web application is contained in a file with a different name, you'll need to adjust the `gunicorn` command from `wsgi` to whatever it is.

Since it looks like you're using Docker to run this, it's also possible that you didn't use the `ADD` command within your `Dockerfile` to copy your `wsgi.py` file into your Docker container. Alternatively, you may have done that, but it's in a different directory than the one you're running the `gunicorn` command from.

Answer (score 4):

Change this:

```
CMD gunicorn -w 3 -b 0.0.0.0:8080 wsgi --reload
```

to this:

```
CMD gunicorn -w 3 -b 0.0.0.0:8080 /full/path/to/wsgi --reload
```

where `/full/path/to/wsgi` is the absolute path of your app--I'm guessing it's `/usr/src/app/wsgi`?)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have the `wsgi.py` file.
I just added it by making the `wsgi.py` file and putting this to the file:

```py
from application import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=False)
```